# Image Source wont show picture

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

I have problem with setting Image Source property... So I tried use every variation of this code and for some reason it won't work.
When I set property manually it works, but when I want to change picture in code it is just blank.

```
        `BitmapImage` bm = new BitmapImage();
         bm.UriSource=new Uri(this.BaseUri,@"\\Assets\logo6.png");
         this.image.Source = image;
```

I use this code inside of button event so I can change picture inside image control.

Comment: what is the name of the control that you are trying to assign the image source to..? try changing this.Image.Source

Comment: Name of control is image... When I press the button the picture that was preloaded just disappear... I really don´t get it...

Comment: perhaps you can show more code especially the code where the button click is happening.. is this for winforms or specifically windwos-phone8

Comment: not sure what you can't just do something like this in theory 
` PictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap("\\Assets\logo6.png`);` also the big question is did you debug this and if so what's the value of bm.URISource when you step past that line..??
this code here makes nosense `this.image.Source = image;` you probably mean `image.Source = bm.UriSource` providing it's a valid path.. try placing the png file in a folder on your local and then assigning the source @"somefilepath\filename.png`

Comment: It is for windows phone 8 and the app starts normally... Same code works when I try to download pics from web but it won´t work when I use local files. And for last suggestion I tried it and I get an error. Maybe it is problem with path to the picture?

Comment: could be a permissions issue too.. can't really tell much from that code that you have there.. would really need to let us know what the values are when you are debugging sorry

Comment: @MatijaSovic If my ans working for you..you can mark it right. :)

Answer (score 1):

you are setting the path in wrong way. try any of these two options it will work.

Also make sure your image property `Build Action is should set to Content` and `Copy To OutPut Directory to Copy to newer` or `Copy Always`

```
BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();
bm.UriSource = new Uri(@"\Assets\Tiles\IconicTileSmall.png",UriKind.Relative);
image.Source = bm;
```

And

```
BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();
bm.UriSource = new Uri("\\Assets\\Tiles\\IconicTileSmall.png",UriKind.Relative);
image.Source = bm;
```

Basically you are mixing these two ways.

Comment: Problem is that I did all those thing and still won`t work. I even try to using copy path in visual studio but all that happens is that image disappear. It is really frustrating.

Comment: @MatijaSovic I have tested it.

Comment: Share your button click event too. I will see what is going wrong ?